# Unable to call instance method inside performSelectorInBackground

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i have a class MatchDayDataController , having a method pushIncompleteDataToServer.

from another class , SummaryVC.m i want to call pushIncompleteDataToServer in performSelectorInBackground.

Code:

```
 MatchDayDataController *sharedDataController = [MatchDayDataController sharedDataController];
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector([sharedDataController pushIncompleteDataToServer]) withObject:nil];
```

It shows some syntax error in performSelectorInBackground. What i missed here? pls guide.

Comment: Try `[sharedDataController performSelectorInBackground:@selector(pushIncompleteDataToServer) withObject:nil];`

Answer (score 3):

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector([sharedDataController pushIncompleteDataToServer]) withObject:nil];
```

This would make the code to search for the method in the same class

It should be:

```
[sharedDataController performSelectorInBackground:@selector(pushIncompleteDataToServer) withObject:nil];
```

which would call the method in the `sharedDataController` class

Also, in the method `performSelectorInBackground: withObject:` the **withObject** is for the parameters to be passed to the selector method. I this case, since there are no parameters, we pass nil.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
[sharedDataController performSelectorInBackground:@selector(pushIncompleteDataToServer) withObject:nil];
```

instead of

```
[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector([sharedDataController pushIncompleteDataToServer]) withObject:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `self` with `sharedDataController`.

```
[sharedDataController performSelectorInBackground:@selector(pushIncompleteDataToServer) withObject:nil];
```

The selector will be performed on the receiver of the `performSelectorInBackground` message, and `self` doesn't implement that method.